# Refreshing and image after upload without refreshing the whole page Java react

Tags: java, reactjs

So im learning java and react and i have a page tha uploads and image sends it to and amazon s3 bucket
and then it gets downloaded to my frontend,but it only updates after i refresh the whole page, the front end uses dropzone to drag and drop the image and send it to my backend i want the image to update when i drop it on the page with out having to refresh the page

this is the method i have to download the image in the back end

```
public byte[] download(String path, String key) {
        try {
            S3Object object = s3.getObject(path, key);
            S3ObjectInputStream objectContent = object.getObjectContent();
            return IOUtils.toByteArray(objectContent);
        }catch (AmazonServiceException | IOException e){
            throw   new IllegalStateException("fail to download  file ", e);
        }
    }
```

and in in the front end im using dropzone to send it

```
function Dropzone({userProfileId}) {
  const onDrop = useCallback(acceptedFiles => {
    // Do something with the files
    const file = acceptedFiles[0];

    console.log(file);
    
    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("file", file);

    axios.post(`http://localhost:3021/api/v1/user-profile/${userProfileId}/image/upload`,
     formData,
    {
     headers:
     {
            
      "Content-type": "multipart/form-data"

     }
    }
    ).then(()=>{
      console.log("file uploaded")
    }).catch(err=>{
      console.log(err);
    })
    
    
  }, []);
  const {getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive} = useDropzone({onDrop})

  return (
    <div {...getRootProps()}>
      <input {...getInputProps()} />
      {
        isDragActive ?
          <p>Drop the files here ...</p> :
          <p>Drag 'n' drop profile image, or click to select profile image</p>
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: If you use a [react hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) for your image and set it's value in the `then` part of the axios REST call, the image should be automatically updated by the react framework, without refreshing the page.